# Непонятное отображение текста в response XHR

Tags: python, grab

Доброго времени суток. Сразу прощу прощения, так как являюсь новичком программирования. <strike>Почему в response XHR текст отображается наполовину непонятными символами, а браузер выводит все нормально?</strike> (На вопрос ответили, спасибо. Прошу ответить на следующий.)

Я получаю текст с помощью python + Grab. И в итоге у меня выходит такое:

> SA÷1¬~ZA÷ALGERIA: Division
>   1¬ZB÷18¬ZC÷8OEJhI14¬ZD÷s¬ZE÷fBVuQEXt¬ZF÷0¬ZO÷0¬ZG÷1¬ZH÷18_zLQAGOBK¬ZJ÷2¬ZL÷/soccer/algeria/division-1/¬ZX÷00Algeria.....007lgeria00000116000Division
>   1..010sion 1¬~AA÷pKxCwGSs¬AD÷1439568000¬AB÷1¬CR÷1¬AC÷1¬CX÷Harrach¬AX÷0¬WM÷HAR¬AE÷Harrach¬WU÷harrach¬OA÷team¬WN÷SAO¬AF÷Saoura¬WV÷saoura¬OB÷team¬AN÷y¬~ZA÷ARGENTINA:
>   Primera C
>   Metropolitana¬ZB÷22¬ZC÷jcyx7Amh¬ZD÷s¬ZE÷YclE8x38¬ZF÷1¬ZO÷0¬ZG÷1¬ZH÷22_zNLhJb1S¬ZJ÷2¬ZL÷/soccer/argentina/primera-c-metropolitana/¬ZX÷00Argentina...009entina00300116000Primera
>   C

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно настроить парсер, чтобы в out.txt выводился нормальный текст:

```
from grab import Grab

def get_content():
  g = Grab(log_file = "out.txt")
  g.setup(headers={
  "X-Fsign": "SW9D1eZo",
  })
g.go("http://d.flashscore.com/x/feed/f_1_0_4_en_1")
print g.response.code

if __name__ == "__main__":
  get_content()
```

Comment: Потому что потом ответ разбирается скриптом и выводится на странице?
В вашем тексте и в веб-инспекторе одно и то же. В чём вопрос?

Comment: @IvanSolntsev, человек хочет распарсить данные чужого сайта, но не знает как это сделать

Comment: @BOPOH, значит ему следует написать это в вопросе. Сейчас вопрос: почему кракозябры? Ответ: всё правильно, в браузере данные обрабатываются.